# How to convert promise to observable angular2?

Tags: angular2-observables

I have used promise in angular2 but my requirement was done by the observable method.

**Component.ts:-**

```
  constructor(private MenuService:MenuService, private router: Router ) {
    this.getMenuPermissions().then(() => this.menuList = this.router.config);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  getMenuPermissions(){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.MenuService.getMenuPermission()
        .subscribe( res => {this.apiResponse = res},
                   err  => reject(),
                   ()   => this.response(this.apiResponse, resolve)
                  );
    });
    return promise;
  }

  response(response, resolve)
  {
    if(response.api_status == 1)
    {
      this.menuPermissions = response.data;
      return resolve();
    }
  }
```

My overall requirement is: - Call the service firstly and the call the HTML function. Using promise method is done but done by the observable method. I have no idea how to do? Please convert this code in the observable method.

Answer (score 0):

You can done like this,

```
Observable.fromPromise(funcReturnsPromise())
```

Comment: which type of file import. please explain in detail

Comment: import import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: I can understand. Please write a code in details. Because I have written a code in my question so please convert all code.

Comment: Sorry.I misunderstood your heading. I think you want to convert a promise to observable

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea how to write an observable code. That way I have mentioned the code in my question. So please explain in detail.

Comment: please refer this https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables_from_other_sources.html